# How do I check if a user left the 'input' or 'raw_input' prompt empty?

Tags: python, python-2.x

How do I check if input has been entered?

For example (python2)

```
x = str(raw_input('Message>> '))
```

or
(python3)

```
y = input('Number>> ')
```

Comment: The input function won't return until something has been entered. Do you mean how to check if the entered input is empty?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You know if nothing was entered for the second one because it will raise a `SyntaxError`. You can catch the error like this:

```
try:
    y=input('Number>> ')
except SyntaxError:
    y = None
```

then test

```
# not just 'if y:' because 0 evaluates to False!
if y is None:
```

or, preferably, use `raw_input`:

```
try:
    y = int(raw_input('Number>> '))
except ValueError:
    print "That wasn't a number!"
```

For the first one, `x` will be an empty string if nothing is entered. The call to `str` is unnecessary -- `raw_input` already returns a string. Empty strings can be tested for explicitly:

```
if x == '':
```

or implicitly:

```
if x:
```

because the only `False` string is an empty string.

Comment: @hochl If just spaces aren't a valid message :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your answer agf and hochl. :)

Comment: What about `if not x:` or `if len(x) < 1:` as alternatives to `if x == '':`, or are those considered bad practice?

Comment: @Dennis See the last code in my post. I do mention using just `if x:` to test emptyness.

Answer (score 1):

This also work too

```
y = input('Number>> ')
while not y:
    y = input('Number>> ')
```

Comment: Simple, self-explanatory 3 line answers are much more preferred. Thanks :)