# coding error msg for typing 'enter'

Tags: python, null

Let's say you're asked for input, such as your age, but instead of putting your age in, you accidentally hit 'enter.' The program, however, ignores the keystroke and goes to the next step. Your age is not entered but is regarded as empty/null value.

How do you code to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the code you're using to get input from the user- `raw_input` or `input`? And Python 2.X or 3?

Comment: Very similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914061/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-left-the-input-or-raw-input-prompt-empty

Comment: You have to validate the value and somehow let the user know/reprompt if the value is invalid. How you do that depends upon how you are prompting the user in the first place (console, GUI, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `while` loop, you do not need to write the `input()` function twice:

```
 while True:
    age = input('>> Age: ')
    if age:
        break
    print('Please enter your age')
```

You might also check if the input is an integer and get an integer from the string. An empty string for `age` will also raise a `ValueError` exception:

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('>> Age: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Incorrect input')
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
age = raw_input("Age: ")
while not age: # In Python, empty strings meet this condition. So does [] and {}. :)
     print "Error!"
     age = raw_input("Age: ")
```

You can create a wrapper function for this.

```
def not_empty_input(prompt):
    input = raw_input(prompt)
    while not input: # In Python, empty strings meet this condition. So does [] and {}. :)
         print "Error! No input specified."
         input = raw_input(prompt)
    return input
```

Then:

```
address = not_empty_input("Address: ")
age = not_empty_input("Age: ")
```